# How to send both HTML and Javascript through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve HTML and Javascript from the same page using AJAX calls. However, I'm not sure what the best, cleanest, and safest way to do this is. I want my Javascript to edit an already defined object on the client. So far, my idea is:

Client-side script executed on some event:

```
getMoreStuff = function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/someRoute',
    success: function (data) {
      $data = $(data);
      $things = $data.find('#things');
      $('#content').append($things);
      // Execute the script
    }
  })
}
```

Body of AJAX request:

```
<div id="things">
  <div class="post">...</div>
  <div class="post">...</div>
  <div class="post">...</div>
  <div class="post">...</div>
  <div class="post">...</div>
</div>
<script>
  (function() {
    window.things || (window.things = []);
    things.concat([...some array...]);
  })();
</script>
```

I'm not sure if my jQuery code executes it when I define `$data`. Or should I send the script as a string and use eval?

Would this work?

```
$(document.body).append($data.find('script'));
```

Comment: what is the nature of the things array in the document youre firing the ajax from and what gets `concat`ed on to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See dataType [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated
>   when inserted in the DOM.

Comment: thanks, simple answer. never used `dataType` before, but I suppose I won't need to since it will automatically and correctly infer my content as HTML.

Comment: Yes, as long as the mimetype is right.  I didn't mean you **needed** dataType though, I just meant to point you to the source of the quote/documentation.