# xhr.responseText returned null with POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is how my js look like

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://myajaxurl.com/lyric", true);
var data = "lyric";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

    console.log(xhr.responseText);

  }
}
xhr.send(data);
```

and my simple php

```
 <?php 
        if( isset($_POST['lyric']) )
        { ?>
            <?php echo "test"; ?>
//it take sometime for my php to work and return the result, i do data scraping here
    <?php } ?>
```

I expect to see 'test' in console.log but I didn't, the ajax need send. why??

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to access the data incorrectly. You need to pass the parameters just like you would do if you were making a GET request. So in the below code, the data variable can be accessed through the $_POST array, which stores the data you want.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://myajaxurl.com/lyric", true);
    var data1 = "data=lyric";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

        console.log(xhr.responseText);

      }
    }
    xhr.send(data1);
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php 
   if( isset($_POST['data']) )
        {
            echo "test";
        } 
  ?>
```

**EDIT**

The header issue can be solved like this

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("POST", "http://myajaxurl.com/lyric", true);
 var data1 = "data=lyric";
 http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data1.length);
 http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

         console.log(xhr.responseText);

     }
}
xhr.send(data1);
```

source:http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why.

Comment: xhr.send(data1)? is that a typo?

Comment: No, its not. I just wanted to differentiate between the variables, you could use data too though. You were trying to access the wrong variable in your POST array.

Comment: The parameters have to be passed just like we send it in a GET request

Comment: @rahulmr Put that in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: it make sense but still returned nothing, now I suspect it's header issue

Comment: I start to see something when I addded this xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

but how to escape those html tag? json encode my echo in my php file?

Comment: can you please explain, i cannot see any HTML tag

Comment: say if my php isn't just echo something but it;s a file that contain css and all those thing, in my ajax callback I saw even html tag is included.

Comment: I don't think it is required. Escaping is required when data is sent to the server so as to store it correctly. I have used AJAX without escaping the HTML and it works great.

Comment: like in my php, I got use things like jquery

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237419/how-to-send-both-html-and-javascript-through-ajax

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't seem to be able to decode a single parameter with no value when doing a post request. A simple solution would be to explicitly add `=` after the parameter name:

```
var data = "lyric=";
```

Example:

```
// index.php
print_r($_POST);

// command line
// parameter name, not value
$ curl --data "lyric" http://localhost:8888/index.php
Array
(
)

// parameter name with empty value
$ curl --data "lyric=" http://localhost:8888/index.php
Array
(
    [lyric] =>
)
```

Compare to GET instead (with `print_r($_GET)`):

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/index.php?foo
Array
(
    [foo] =>
)
```

Comment: I added this and start to see some result, but it include those html tag. what should I do to only get the echo part of my php file?

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: You mean the PHP script returns HTML? Simple don't output the HTML when the parameter is set.

Comment: I put this  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

to start seeing something, if I use text/plain type I see null result.